# Сортировка времени

Tags: java, алгоритм

Из файла txt прочитал несколько строк в формате HH:ММ - HH:ММ, которые являются временем прихода и ухода сотрудников.
На выходе должны получить число, которое показывает максимальное количество сотрудников, которые одновременно находились в течение дня на работе.

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String result;

    while ((result = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
```

Как лучше реализовать сортировку времени?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запишите все времена прихода с меткой плюс, и все времена ухода с меткой минус в одном массиве. Отсортируйте массив по временам. Теперь идите по массиву и за каждое время с меткой плюс увеличивайте счетчик, а с меткой минус - уменьшайте. Когда значение счетчика будет максимальным - это и будет искомое "число, которое показывает максимальное количество сотрудников, которые одновременно находились в течение дня на работе".

Пример, вот восемь меток прихода и ухода отсортированные по времени:

```
П П П П У П У П У П У У П У У У
```

Вот счетчик, после каждой метки:

```
1 2 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 2 3 2 1 0
```

Как видно, больше всего сотрудников было в интервалы:

```
       ^   ^   ^   ^
```

А уж как быть, если приход/уход совпадают с точностью до секунды (сортировать их как `П У` или `У П`) - дело ваше.

Comment: Не понимаю в чём смысл предложенного алгоритма. Предположим, что у нас 6 промежутков это 12 значений времени в массиве, из них ровно половина с + ровно половина с -.

Comment: Если время ухода и прихода одинаково 13:30, то это является пересечением, а счётчик это не учтёт

Comment: Нужно закинуть время старта и окончания в класс, скажем, `Interval implements Comparable<Interval>`, прочитать файл и создать лист `List<Interval>`, отсортировать его по времени старта и с дискретизацией в 1 сек (больше у вас нет данных) проверять, входит ли это время в интервал для каждого элемента листа. Если входит, то добавлять 1 к счетчику. После каждой вычисленной секунды проверять, получили ли мы число больше, чем уже посчитано на предыдущих шагах (как в алгоритме поиска макс или мин элемента)